# Django Model VIewSet overriding

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Models

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product.name} - {self.quantity}"

class InventoryHistory(models.Model):
    inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity_change = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product.name} - {self.quantity_change} ({self.timestamp})"
```

Serializers

```
class InventoryHistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InventoryHistory
        fields = '__all__'

class InventorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = '__all__'
```

ViewSets

```
class InventoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Inventory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InventorySerializer


class InventoryHistoryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = InventoryHistory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InventoryHistorySerializer
```

I'm working with above code. The idea is, When Some changes are made in Inventory, the InventoryHistory gets automatically updated with a new record. My main confusion is, having two different serializers. How can i override viewsets and manage these two different serializers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create new `InventoryHistory` you can override the `.save()` instance of `InventorySerializer` to compute the quantity change an create the new `InventoryHistory`

```py
class InventorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(**kwargs):
        if self.instance is None:
            prior_quantity = 0
        else:
            prior_quantity = self.instance.quantity

        instance = super().save(**kwargs)

        InventoryHistory.objects.create(inventory=self.instance, quantity_change=instance.quantity-prior_quantity)
        return instance
```